# Improving performance of VBA data validation script in Access with large data size

Tags: performance, vba, ms-access

I work in IT compliance and one of my main duties is ensuring the integrity of employee network accounts. Partial VBA script as currently used is shown below:

```
Public Function validateHireDate(hireDate as String)

    If Not IsDate(hireDate) Or IsNull(hireDate) Then
        validateHireDate = "Invalid hire date"
    Else
        validateHireDate = "Hire date reviewed"
    End if
End Function

Public Function validateEmployeeManager(employeeStatus as String, employeeManager as String)

    If employeeStatus <> "Active" Then
        Exit Function
    Else
        If IsNull(employeeManager) Then
            validateEmployeeManager = "Invalid employee manager"
        Else
            validateEmployeeManager = "Employee manager reviewed"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Given that **the size of the database is around 50K of records**, the above code works but is slow. There are several more validation functions such as for social security numbers, email, and user account control (disabled or enabled) depending on multiple criteria. Presently, the source data report is run bimonthly from which I import the results into Microsoft Access for auditing.

**Is there a more efficient manner in which the validation can be done?**

Comment: How are you calling this function? Given the record size, I'm assuming you're using this function in a query. Is that right?

Comment: Use the where clause in a query to limit the records, don't use VBA function for that as it's going to be super inefficient

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of micro-optimizations to be made. They probably won't give you the boost you're looking for, but it's worth trying.

First, you can explicitly define the return type. When you don't define one, the compiler defines it as a `Variant` type, which incurs a lot of overheard compared to the "regular" data types.

For clarity, this

> ```
> Public Function validateHireDate(hireDate as String)
> ```

Is equivalent to this

```
Public Function validateHireDate(hireDate as String) As Variant
```

And really should be

```
Public Function validateHireDate(hireDate as String) As String
```

But I find it a bit odd that a validation routine is returning a string. I would consider returning a boolean instead. It has a smaller memory footprint than a string and is, *in theory*, faster than a string.

---

The second thing you can do is manually short circuit the logic, but you'll have to sacrifice some DRYness to do it.

> ```
> If Not IsDate(hireDate) Or IsNull(hireDate) Then
>     validateHireDate = "Invalid hire date"
> Else
>     validateHireDate = "Hire date reviewed"
> End if
> ```

VBA does't have short circuiting logical operations, so no matter what the return value of `IsDate(hireDate)` is, `IsNull(hireDate)` executes every time as well. We can unroll the logic a bit to make it more efficient, but be sure to leave a comment explaining your actions to your future self. If you're anything like me, you'll instantly want to undo this optimization the next time you see it if there's nothing telling you not to.

```
If IsNull(hireDate) Then
    validateHireDate = "Invalid hire date"

Else If Not IsDate(hireDate) Then
    validateHireDate = "Invalid hire date"

Else
    validateHireDate = "Hire date reviewed"
End if
```

Now, the order here maybe important, and I might not have it right. First, verify that `IsDate()` can handle a null value. If it can, then you need to study the data to determine which is the more common error state. You want the most common case to come first in order to optimize the logic.

---

I like your `validateEmployeeManager` function. You're evaluating the most likely situation first and exiting as fast as possible. You can explicitly declare the return type, but I see no further room for optimization. It's a well written function.

---

Finally, I would just encourage you to think about whether you need to do this in VBA at all. Access is a SQL based program and, like any SQL, it's better to use set based operations than procedure based ones. I would argue that it's perhaps even more important with Access. You've already noticed how slow the COM based VBA interaction is compared to a regular query, so why not move this logic into a query, or a series of queries? You're not doing anything here that can't be accomplished with the `IIF` and `ISNULL` functions. Even a faithful translation *should* be faster than even the optimized version of the VBA code. Although, I would also encourage you to investigate ways to do this truly set based instead.

Some psuedo-SQL for your first function.

```
SELECT IIF(ISNULL(Emp.HireDate),"Invalid",IIF(ISDATE(Emp.HireDate,"Invalid","Reviewed"))
FROM Employees
```

That's the faithful translation. I would find out if the requirements can be adjusted to only return the records that are in error. If the valid records are of no interest to the business, then something like this becomes possible.

```
SELECT * --don't actually select all
FROM Employees
WHERE HireDate IS NULL
    OR (NOT ISDATE(HireDate))
```

Which returns only the invalid records.